# Fix uneven Rectangle patch width in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, rectangles

The code I currently have draws a set of rectangles on a plot. But, upon zooming in, one can see that the widths of the rectangles are not the same. The result I get now is this:
[image]
So far, I've tried changing various options of the rectangle object like aliasing, linewidth, the x-position, but nothing helps maintain consistent width across all bars. My guess is that this has something to do with DPI-figurewidth calculation and that since I know the no. of bars and width of a bar beforehand, maybe I can manually set the width of the plot to accommodate all the bars so that they all have the same size. But I'm not sure how to go about this method and I'd really appreciate any help regarding this.

I have no specific constraints regarding bar width. I know the no. of bars I am going to plot and can adjust the data points to fit the figure size or adjust figure size according to no. of data points - but I don't know if this will achieve the effect I want or if I'm missing something else entirely.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def draw_bar(ax,n,data,o,c):
    color = 'red' if data%2==0 else 'green'
    rect_vol = Rectangle(
        xy=(n, 0),
        width=0.5,
        height=data,
        edgecolor='black',
        facecolor=color,
        linewidth=0,
        antialiased=True,
        alpha=0.4
    )
    ax.add_patch(rect_vol)

N = 75
max_height = 50
data_collection = np.random.randint(5,max_height,N)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=72)
plt.margins(0)
ax = plt.subplot2grid((4,6), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=6)
ax.set_label('XYZ')
ax.xaxis.grid(True,linestyle='--')
ax.yaxis.grid(True,linestyle='--')
ax.set_xlim(0,N)
ax.set_ylim(0,max_height)

for n, (data) in enumerate(data_collection):
    draw_bar(ax,n,data,np.random.choice(10),np.random.choice(10))

plt.show()
```

Comment: You chose a dpi of 72. Hence the bar width is only a few pixels, sometimes 3 sometimes 4, because there are no half-pixels. If you chose a dpi of say 600, the problem would not occur.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just tried your suggestion. I made the DPI 100 but the widths are still uneven. 600 is too big for my application and takes too long to render. Is there an exact calculation I can use to make sure I don't have half-pixels?

Comment: I mean you *could* do all the math needed to make sure bars are at integer pixel positions... but I'm not sure that's worth it.